# How data migration from one table to an other happen in Google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

1) Let say I have an application which has to be upgraded to a newer version.

In the newer version data form a table has to be moved to an another table before the application goes   live.

How could this be achieved in a Google App Engine?

2) How could I switch over my application from one version to another. I know that GAE supports up to ten version of the same application. But how could I switch over between these versions?

Comment: Are you using the datastore or cloudsql, as there are no tables in the datastore, and you wouldn't move them, but you might change the model and perform some form of update.

Comment: @TimHoffman Thanks for the response! I'm using datastore. Could you please provide some details on what kind of update has to be done?

Answer (score 0):

1. why do you need to move data?
2. just deploy, give a name to the new version and change the default version to pointing to new one / split the traffic. Why do you need to maintain the old one?

Comment: 1) The current system holds EmailId and SSN(User can provide any one value) values in the same column(No reason it was done this way). The newer version should save these values in a different table. Because as per the newer requirement all the secured data of a user like Bank details, SSN should be stored in a separate table.

Comment: You are missing a basic understanding of what/how appengine works. Provide the two different versions of the model that contains the properties you are working with. You will need to run a migration process possibly working with raw entities.  If you provide the model then we can give an explicit example.